# In WordPress, wp_mail is not sending mails for my Custom Form

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmailer

Below code should send email on form submission:

```
function form_submit() {

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    // get the info from the form
    $to = sanitize_email($_POST['email']);

    // The email subject
    $subject = 'you got mail';

    // Build the message
    $message = 'Message from...';

    //set the form headers
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'From: Me <onlineform@example.com');

    //send the mail
    $sendmail = wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    return $sendmail;
}
}
```

Any assistance on what should be corrected?
I have even tried authenticating `wp_mail` with my SMTP server using below code:
Source (https://gist.github.com/butlerblog/c5c5eae5ace5bdaefb5d)

```
add_action('phpmailer_init', 'send_smtp_email');

function send_smtp_email($phpmailer) {

$phpmailer->isSMTP();
$phpmailer->Host = 'example.com';
$phpmailer->SMTPAuth = true;
$phpmailer->Port = '465';
$phpmailer->Username = 'me@example.com';
$phpmailer->Password = 'password';
$phpmailer->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$phpmailer->From = 'me@example.com';
$phpmailer->FromName = 'Me';
}
```

**Update #1**

In WordPress v.5.8.2, below form is sending the plain text mail:

```
function form_submit() {

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    // get the info from the form
    $to = sanitize_email($_POST['email']);

    // The email subject
    $subject = 'you got mail';

    // Build the message
    $message = 'Message from...';

    //set the form headers
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';
    $headers[] = 'From: Me <onlineform@example.com';

    //send the mail
    wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
  }
}
```

With below code, I am trying to send the SMTP mail:

```
add_action('phpmailer_init', 'send_smtp_email');

function send_smtp_email(PHPMailer $phpmailer) {

$phpmailer->isSMTP();
$phpmailer->Host = 'example.com';
$phpmailer->SMTPAuth = true;
$phpmailer->Port = '465';
$phpmailer->Username = 'me@example.com';
$phpmailer->Password = 'password';
$phpmailer->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$phpmailer->From = 'me@example.com';
$phpmailer->FromName = 'Me';
$phpmailer->send();
if (!$phpmailer->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $phpmailer->ErrorInfo;
}
}
```

With above cannot send SMTP mail.

Comment: the returned value of the wp_mail() function ($sendmail) is false?

Comment: No, it should be true. You can correct if it should be.

Comment: I know it should be true, I'm asking if it's false in order to determine where's the problem :)

Comment: The problem is I don't see the mails are being sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the working PHPmailer code:

```
add_action('phpmailer_init', 'send_smtp_email');

function send_smtp_email($phpmailer) {

$phpmailer->isSMTP();
$phpmailer->Host = 'example.com';
$phpmailer->SMTPAuth = true;
$phpmailer->Port = '465';
$phpmailer->Username = 'me@example.com';
$phpmailer->Password = 'password';
$phpmailer->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$phpmailer->From = 'me@example.com';
$phpmailer->FromName = 'Me';
}
```

I have just removed `PHPMailer` from `function send_smtp_email(PHPMailer $phpmailer) {` and I am able to send mails through SMTP account.

Answer (score 0):

Uh, you're not actually telling it to send! You're setting a bunch of settings and that's all. You need to call `send()` in order for it to actually send anything. Add this (includes basic error handling):

```
if (!$phpmailer->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $phpmailer->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Comment: should i add this to `form_submit()` or `send_smtp_email($phpmailer)`?

Comment: In whichever one you want the send to happen in, presumably the latter.

Comment: It did not worked.